# How to get the value of DIV id to POST FORM in PHP and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

hello i would like to get the value of a div to a php form. i am using POST.

this is my code , this div also runs on jQuery , the value is changing depends on what color the user chooses:

```
<div id="caption">Alumina Jade Metallic</div>
```

***UPDATE***

this the code for the dynamic onchange of `div id = "caption"`

```
   <span data-src="vios-color/vios_AJM.jpg" data-caption="Alumina Jade Metallic"><a href="#?" class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-Alumina-Jade.png">  </a></span>
                            <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_B.jpg" data-caption="Black Metallic"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Black.png"> </a></span>
                            <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_BRM.jpg" data-caption="Blackish Red Metallic"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Black-Red.png"> </a></span>
                            <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_BMM.jpg" data-caption="Blue Metallic"><a href="#?"class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-Blue-Metal.png"></a></span>
                            <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_FW.jpg" data-caption="Freedom White"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Freedom-White.png"> </a></span>
                            <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_OM.jpg" data-caption="Orange Metallic"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Orange-Metal.png"> </a></span>
                            <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_RMM.jpg" data-caption="Red Metallic"><a href="#?"class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-Red-Metal.png">  </a></span>
                            <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_SM.jpg" data-caption="Silver Metallic"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Silver-Metal.png">  </a></span>
                            <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_WP.jpg" data-caption="White Pearl"><a href="#?"class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-White-Pearl.png"> </a></span>
                         </div>
```

and this is the jQuery that i used :

```
$('.thumb span').each(function(){
  var _this = $(this);
  var src = _this.data("src");
  var text = _this.data("caption");
  _this.find('a').click(function(){
     $("#image").show( function() {
    $(".img img").attr("src", src);
    $("#caption").text(text);
     });
 });
});
```

i used `data-caption` to change the data of div `#caption`

and this is my sample php POST :

```
$action = $_POST['action'];

    $fName = $_POST['form'][0]['fName'];
    $lName = $_POST['form'][0]['lName'];
    $address = $_POST['form'][0]['address'];
    $doBirth = $_POST['form'][0]['doBirth'];
    $city = $_POST['form'][0]['city'];
    $zipCode = $_POST['form'][0]['zipCode'];
    $email = $_POST['form'][0]['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['form'][0]['phone'];
    $remarks = $_POST['form'][0]['remarks'];
```

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you want to do? You said you use jQuery, yet I can't see any jquery. The name in your html and the way you get data using POST is very different

Comment: @Swellar added it

Answer (score 0):

### alternative 1:

you can add input hidden e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="colors" id="colors">` inside your `<form>` which is the value dynamically changed along with the `<div>` based on color the user chooses.

for example:

```
$('#colorSelect').on('input',function() {
    var val = $('#colorSelect').val().join();
    $('#caption').text(val);
    $('#colors').val(val);
});
```

then on your PHP you will retrieve `$_POST['colors']`

### alternative 2:

use jQuery `$.post()` function, example:

```
$.post('ProcessData.php',{colors:$('#caption').text(),data1:...,data2:...,etc},function(status) {
    alert(status);
});
```

you will retrieve the `<div>`'s text in `$_POST['colors']`

Comment: should it be like this ? <div id="caption"><input type="hidden" name="colors" id="colors">Alumina Jade Metallic</div>

Comment: @jmv outside the `<div>`, like immediately after `<form>` tag or before `</form>` tag

Comment: where should i put this #colorSelect?